# Как связать физические и логические диски windows в python

Tags: python, winapi, powershell, wmi

Я хочу получить информацию аналогичную выводу PS скрипта `Get-Partition | Select-Object DiskNumber, PartitionNumber, DriveLetter, Offset, Size, Type | ConvertTo-Json`.
В выводе скрипта поле DiskNumber является номером физического диска.

Я попробовал использовать `wmi`

```
import wmi
for p in wmi.WMI().Win32_DiskPartition():
for prop in p.properties:
    print(prop, getattr(p, prop))
```

Но у томов полученных этим методом нет имени, например `С:`

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ на вопрос](https://www.programmersought.com/article/37064644486/)

```py
def get_fs_info():
    tmplist = []
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for physical_disk in c.Win32_DiskDrive():
        for partition in physical_disk.associators("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
            for logical_disk in partition.associators("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
                tmpdict = {}
                tmpdict["Caption"] = logical_disk.Caption
                tmpdict["DiskTotal"] = round(int(logical_disk.Size) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2)
                tmpdict["DeviceID"] = logical_disk.DeviceID
                tmpdict["PhysicalDiskIndex"] = physical_disk.Index
                tmpdict["FileSystem"] = logical_disk.FileSystem
                tmplist.append(tmpdict)
    return tmplist
```